# Dijit horizontal slider color issue

Tags: javascript, esri, dijit.form, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to implement a Horizontal Slider using 'dijit/form/HorizontalSlider'. I successfully got the Slider working but the slider comes with a red color.. How can I change the color to white or any color that I want? Below is the code snippet that I'm using.

```js
   

 createSlider= function() {
      sliderOpacity = new HorizontalSlider({
       name: "slider",
       value: 60,
       minimum: 0,
       maximum: 100,
       intermediateChanges: true
      }, "sliderOpacity");
      sliderOpacity.startup();
      dojo.connect(dijit.byId('sliderOpacity'), 'onChange', changeOpacity);
    },
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <div id="sliderOpacity">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: CSS? I recommend you start with an existing dijit theme closest to what you want and override the styles to customize it to your needs. That's the easiest way.

Comment: The tundra theme has white sliders by default. http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.8.0/dojo-release-1.8.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=tundra